# Adding subviews with time delay on UISlider?

Tags: ios, nstimer, uiviewanimation, uislider

I have a `UISlider` and I am trying to add subviews **dynamically** on the track of the `UISlider` with animation. I need 1 second time delay before adding each subview. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic setup of how you can go about achieving it:

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSTimer *_timer;
    CGRect sliderFrame;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.slider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
    self.slider.maximumValue = 100.0f;

    sliderFrame = self.slider.frame;

    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(addLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [_timer fire];
}

- (void) addLabel:(NSTimer*) timer {      
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sliderFrame.origin.x + self.slider.value/100 * self.slider.frame.size.width, sliderFrame.origin.y - 10, 20, 20)];
    label.text = @"1";
    [self.view addSubview:label];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an animation block, then, within your block you can use setAnimationDelay. For example;

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:
 ^{
     [UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
     ...
  } completion:^(BOOL finished){
     ...        
  }];
```

This would do a 5 second animation with a delay of 1 second before it started.

Answer (score 0):

you can hook up the valueChangeEvent with an action method.

You can put an animation block in that method with passing the seconds to wait before starting an animation as delay parameter.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) delay:(NSTimeInterval) options:(UIViewAnimationOptions) animations:^(void)animations completion:^(BOOL finished)completion]
```

then you can change add the view with whatever animation your require.